# There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created a form in Angular 2 with which users can edit a `SearchProfile` which they can select from a list. Initially everything works fine but when i select a different item from the list of `SearchProfile`s I receive the following exception:
`There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: controlName`.
The whole thing consists of 3 elements: 2 components `SelectProfileComponent`, `SearchProfileComponent` and a service `ProfileService`. `ProfileService` contains the `ActiveProfile` which is the selected `SearchProfile` for editing.
`ProfileService` looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {
    private activeProfileSource = new ReplaySubject<ISearchProfile>();
    activeProfile$ = this.activeProfileSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.selectProfile();
    }

    public getSearchProfile(profileId: number = null): Observable<ISearchProfile> {
        let url = `<url>?profileid=${profileId}`;
        this.http.get(url).map((result) => {
            return <ISearchProfile>.result.json();
        });
    }

    public selectProfile(profileId: number = null) {
        this.getSearchProfile(profileId).subscribe((p) => {
            this.activeProfileSource.next(p);
        });
    }
}
```

`SelectProfileComponent` contains a list with profile which triggers a `change`-event when a `SearchProfile` is selected.

```
<select (change)="setActiveProfile($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let profile of profiles" [value]="profile.Id" [innerHtml]="profile.name"></option>
</select>

export class ProfileSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
    private profiles: ISearchProfile[] = null;

    constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {}

    //get profiles logic

    public setActiveProfile(profileId: number): void {
        this.profileService.selectProfile(profileId);
    }
}
```

The `SearchProfileComponent` has a `Subscription` to the `activeProfile` and should show the properties of the `activeProfile` so the user can edit them.
`SearchProfileComponent` looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="searchProfile.name" />
</form>

export class SearchProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    private isLoading: boolean = true;
    private activeProfileSubscription: Subscription;
    private searchProfile: ISearchProfile = null;
    public profileForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private profilService: ProfileService
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activeProfileSubscription = this.profileService.activeProfile$.subscribe((profile: ISearchProfile) => {
            this.searchProfile = profile;
            this.createForm();
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }
    private createForm() {
        this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ["name"]: [this.searchProfile.name, null]
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I solved it in this way:

Before:

```
formControlName="description"
```

After:

```
[formControl]="form.controls['description']"
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuzenko Lubko this is working! I was wondering, this looks like a bug, can you tell why `formControlName` isn't working in this case?

Comment: @benshabatnoam maybe because form will be created after async request. If you are using formControlName you should have form created before view render.

Comment: You're kind of right, I'm building the `formGroup` dynamically after the view was rendered, but I have an `*ngIf` on my form. I guess this is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I was only crashing on my up/down arrows in my number control, this cured it. So it was something happening with the view rendering.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by initializing form once in the component constructor
i.e.

```
constructor() {
        this.form = this.initForm();
}
```

OR

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.initForm();
}
```

and remove the re-initialization of the form in the component anywhere in the component without constructor
i.e.

```
this.form = this.initForm();
```

Comment: Thanks, My issue was due to else condition in edit form, where I was checking for data to fill the form or if data is not present then re-initializing the form. @Saad

Answer (score 4):

The creation of your `FormGroup` is a little bit wrong. You dont need to wrap the control name in brackets and double quotes. Read more about [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) on official angular docs.

Change your creation of FormGroup from this:

```
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ["name"]: [this.searchProfile.name, null]
});
```

to this:

```
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: [this.searchProfile.name]
});
```

And you should make some changes in your html. Hint: If you are using reactive forms, you don't need `[(ngModel)]` on inputs, remove that. Here is right html for you input:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found that using the `[formControl]="$form.something"` method worked well. Clunky, but that's Angular for you.